# Error "cannot assign a value of type" in prepareForSegue method (Swift, Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, segue

I just want to make a segue by an example here http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-uitableviewcell-taps-swift/

But when I made this code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == blogSegueIdentifier {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? specialitiesViewController {
            if let cellIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
                destination.formuleName = formulesList[cellIndex]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Appeared error called:

> cannot assign a value of type '(Formules)'  to a value of type String"

this is a class which contents a data for `formuleList`

`formuleList` is an array with a list of cell names

how to remove error?
Thank u for your help.

Comment: Your error is very clear, share more info about `formuleName` and the `Formules` type

Comment: You could try to do a class extension for your Cell type to implement `Printable` which adds a `description` method that auto-will convert it into a string?

Answer (score 0):

The way that this segue block works is you are basically telling the UI that I'm going to segue to the next view controller

`if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? specialitiesViewController` - says that the `ViewController` we are going to is of custom type `specialitiesViewController`

My assumption would be that in your `specialitiesViewController` you have a variable called `forumlaName` that is of type `String` and that your `formulesList` is of type `[Formules]` - and as such this assignment is invalid.

You are trying to assign a specific `Formules` to a `String` and thus occurs your error.

Fix choices would be to make sure the type `Formules` implements one of the String protocols such as `Printable` that allows it to be represented as a string.  Alternativley perhaps you have something like a `name` variable inside that is a string

Depending on the version of Swift you are using you could do something like:

```
extension Formules : Printable {

   override public var description: String {

            return "TEST"
    }
}
```

but with out more actual code info i can't tell you if this will actually work